# Is there any way to simplify complex if else statement in swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have a long if else condition to assign a text to a UILabel. So i am looking for a better option/logic to write less number of lines.
Below is my condition,

```
if numberOfTeachers == 4 && numberOfStudents == 27 {
      if String(interval.day! + 1) == "1" {
        self.daysLabel.text = "1st"
        self.testLabel.isHidden = true
        self.subjectLabel.text = "Physics"
        self.dayTitleLabel.text = "Today is your first day"
      } else if String(interval.day! + 1) == "2" {
        self.daysLabel.text = "2nd"
        self.testLabel.isHidden = true
        self.subjectLabel.text = "Chemistry"
        self.dayTitleLabel.text = "Today is your Second day"
      } else if String(interval.day! + 1) == "3" {
        self.daysLabel.text = "3rd"
        self.subjectLabel.isHidden = true
        self.unitLabel.text = "Mathematics"
        self.dayTitleLabel.text = "Today is your Third day"}  
else if String(interval.day! + 1) == "4" {
        self.daysLabel.text = "4th"
        self.testLabel.isHidden = false
        self.subjectLabel.text = "Physics"
        self.dayTitleLabel.text = "Today is your fourth day"      }
else if numberOfTeachers == 4 && numberOfStudents == 28 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 4 && numberOfStudents == 29 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 4 && numberOfStudents == 30 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 5 && numberOfStudents == 27 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 5 && numberOfStudents == 28 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 5 && numberOfStudents == 29 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 5 && numberOfStudents == 30 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 6 && numberOfStudents == 27 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 6 && numberOfStudents == 28 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 6 && numberOfStudents == 29 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 6 && numberOfStudents == 30 {
       
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 7 && numberOfStudents == 27 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 7 && numberOfStudents == 28 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 7 && numberOfStudents == 29 {
        
 } else if numberOfTeachers == 7 && numberOfStudents == 30 {
        
 }
```

there are atleast 4 more conditions inside every if condition like (4,27), (4,28) , (5,27), (5,28)....so on.
So this whole condition is getting too long.

Comment: You could use nested `if`s or `switch`es, that may not result in fewer lines but will avoid repetition and make the code easier to read.

Comment: What are you doing inside the guards? Sometimes there is the option to not use `if` or `switch` statements at all but calculating the result directly from the input values (`numberOfTeachers` and `numberOfStudents` in this case).

Comment: I like what @Felix is suggesting here, perhaps a better solution is to calculate the ratio of teachers to students and that will help reduce the number of lines in your logic sequence? If that is not possible in your domain and you must be so explicit then realistically you must attempt to nest your conditions to reduce repetition.

Comment: What happens inside these statements' bodies? That might shed light on a way this can be simplified

Comment: @Alexander Inside these statement's body i am assigning different text to three labels depending on the above conditions.

Comment: How many different text values are there? What are they like?

Comment: @Alexander Inside every statement, there are also 5 more conditions as below :- 
/*
if String(interval.day! + 1) == "1" {
     self.daysLabel.text = "1st"
     self.testLabel.isHidden = true
     self.subjectLabel.text = "Physics"
     self.dayTitleLabel.text = "Today is your first day"
 } else if String(interval.day! + 1) == "2" {
    self.daysLabel.text = "2nd"
    self.testLabel.isHidden = true
    self.subjectLabel.text = "Chemistry"
    self.dayTitleLabel.text = "Today is your Second day"
 }...upto String(interval.day! + 1) == "5"

Comment: @AbhishekKumar can you please just edit that into your answer? Comments can't have formatted  code

Comment: @Alexander i have edited my question in "if (4,27)" condition. 
I need to write these child "if condition" inside every parent "if condition".
In that way it is becoming much long and nested function.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Interesting. I don't understand how these label values are at related to the `numberOfTeachers` and `numberOfStudents` checks they're nested within. Could you shed some light on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245501/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-alexander).

Answer (score 0):

You could nest the `if` conditions like:

```
if numberOfTeachers == 4
{
    if numberOfStudents == 29 {}
    else if ...
}
else if ...
```

You could also use a [`switch`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) statement which is a great alternative for long chains of if-else:

```
switch numberOfTeachers
{
    case value 4:
        // handle number of students
    case value 5:
        ...
    default:
        // error?
}
```

**Edit** as *Martin R* noted, one could also use:

```
switch (numberOfTeachers, numberOfStudents)
{
    case (4, 27):
        // handle number of students
    case (5, 28):
        ...
    default:
        // error?
}
```

Comment: You can also switch on a tuple: `switch (numberOfTeachers, numberOfStudents) { case (4, 27): ...`

Comment: For now i am using nested if condition because i find it is making code little bit easy to read as compare to other logics.

Comment: Thats fine and mostly dependent on personal preference. May I still ask what you are doing inside the cases? What is the task that is to be performed depending on `numberOf...`s?

Comment: Inside the cases i am assigning different text to three labels depending on the above conditions.

Comment: Ok, so unless there are 16 different texts for your 16 possible cases, it might be possible to find some schema which can be used. If you like you can tell me what is to be dislayed in wich case so I can try to figure it out. Then again, having a complicated schama might make the code harder to read.

Comment: @Felix lets have discussion on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245454/discussion-between-felix-and-abhishek-kumar).